# Vim package management

Tags: filetype-c++, packages, plugin-pathogen

I have not kept up with `vim` in the last decade. I have had my setup and it worked well enough that I have not bothered touching my configuration in forever.

BUT. I have the need to get back into some programming and want to see if what I need to update. The first thing is package management. I currently use [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) it now has a git page!. This project looks like it has not been updated in 5 years and even the home page suggest I use `built-in package management`.

Any suggestions of package management specifically for C++ programmer (and how to convert from pathogen). :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pathogen has always been a very stable piece of software. It still works and will probably keep doing so for a long time, so there is no real hard need to look for an alternative, IMO.

Anyway, the wording in Pathogen's README is unfortunate because, just like Pathogen itself, `:help packages` is not a proper "package management" solution. It would need the ability to download packages, handle dependency management, trigger builds, etc. for that, which it doesn't. It is just a new way to organize plugins that is more convenient than the old way. Just like Pathogen used to be.

And in many ways, the new system is a formalization of how Pathogen worked: you put your plugins in dedicated directories under a common root and you let Vim add those directories to `:help` 'runtimepath'`. Therefore, migrating your setup from Pathogen to "packages" is very easy.

All you need to do is…

1. Remove any Pathogen-related lines from your `vimrc`:

   ```
   $ vim
   :e $MYVIMRC
   :g/pathogen/d
   :x
   ```
2. Remove `pathogen.vim` from `~/.vim/autoload`:

   ```
   $ rm ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim
   ```
3. Create the necessary directory structure:

   ```
   $ mkdir -p ~/.vim/pack/bundle/start
   ```
4. And move the content of your `bundle` directory to its new home:

   ```
   $ mv ~/.vim/bundle ~/.vim/pack/bundle/start
   ```

NOTE:

- You can name the `bundle` directory however you want. I kept `bundle`, here, to make things more familiar.
- Read `:help packages` carefully, specifically the part about optional packages.
- In this context, `bundle` is a "package"—a number of plugins packaged together—, and you can have several of them, which is good for organization. For example, I still have a `bundle` package (I switched from Pathogen, too) for my QOL plugins, but I also have a `lang` package for all my programming language-related plugins, and a `lab` package for my own experimental stuff.

If you actually want proper package *management*, the most popular plugin manager is currently [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug).

Comment: Thanks for the extended info.

Answer (score 1):

1. Vim "plugin" is simply a collection of scripts lying under one of `&runtimepath` nodes.
2. Therefore it is possible to merge any "plugin" under your `~/.vim/` directory tree and it will work right away.
3. However, your `~/.vim/` will then become a total mess.
4. Instead of this, you can add whole "plugin" tree as a node into `&runtimepath`
5. People are too lazy to populate list of directories manually, so "pathogen" was invented. Basically, you call a single function and `&runtimepath` gets flooded by many nodes at once.
6. But this thought to be too hard, so now "pathogen" is a builtin called `:help packages`. That is, you copy (or symlink) all your plugins under `~/.vim/pack/*/start/` (or any other node under `&packpath`) and they all magically get to `&runtimepath` on startup.
7. This is still too hard for some of us, as we still need to type `$ git pull` etc. by hand. So there are also multiple "plugin managers" that can execute `git` many times and show the output in a nice fashion. Personally, I use `minpac` but they all more or less similar. All you need is to `$ git clone` one of them and follow the instructions.

Comment: Thanks you. Very helpful.